# Python & Pandas: Add a link to existing field

Tags: python, pandas

In my `pandas` table, the `url` is in `['douban_info']['alt']`, I want to use it to turn the existing field `['db_rating']` into a link, maybe something like

```
pd_data['db_rating'] = '<a href=pd_data['douban_info']['alt'] >pd_data['db_rating']</a>'
```

but this above certainly doesn't work, I can only do something like:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 500)
# link is in ['douban_info']['alt']
pd_data['link'] = pd_data['douban_info'].apply(lambda x:  x['alt'])
pd_data['a'] = pd_data['link'].apply(lambda x: '<a href="{0}">link</a>'.format(x))
# drop redundent info to make table look better
pd_data = pd_data.drop('douban_info', 1)
pd_data = pd_data.drop('omdb_info', 1)
pd_data = pd_data.drop('link', 1)
HTML(pd_data[0:5].to_html(escape=False))
```

This can only add a new `a` field, which produces 
[image]

There're certain thing that's really annoying:

1. To get data from json(['douban_info']), I only know to use
   `pd_data['link'] = pd_data['douban_info'].apply(lambda x:  x['alt'])`
2. I only know to use info from one field to another. In the case above, from `link` to `a`. I don't know how to use `link` and incoporate it into `db_rating`, how can I do it?

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: It seems that the douban_info column in your dataframe contains dict object. Can you post some example data?

Comment: @HYRY, just updated, it's just an url, in `['douban_info']['alt']`

Comment: so `pd_data.ix[1, "douban_info"]` is a dict, how do you get this pd_data?

Comment: @HYRY, the original data is  `json`, I just dump it into `dataframe`, so the inner nested format turned into `dict`.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use DataFrame for this kind of data. I think it's better to process the data as a list of dict. You can use list comprehension to get the result.

Comment: @HYRY, Any specific reason not using `pandas`? Beccause I need to manipulate data, and plot (as you've seen in the table), is there any other good options?

Comment: You can calculate the link list first, and convert the data you need into a DataFrame.

Comment: Can we have a sample JSON file to work with?

Comment: @LondonRob, surely, but where can I upload it?